# How to avoid Insert mode mappings during pasting in Insert mode?

Tags: vim, paste

I have some Insert mode mappings like :

```
inoremap ( ()<ESC>i
```

Its quite handy to auto-insert brackets . However I I paste something like `Hello()` , this mapping gets triggered causing side effects .

How can I avoid Insert mode mappings during paste scenario in Insert mode ?

I know I can do a Normal mode paste like `"+p` , but I am looking for any vim hooks to prevent insert mode mappings in Insert Mode paste scenario .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what

```
:set paste
```

is for. It's mostly for pasting from the terminal, but in GVIM, it also disables insert mode mappings, and that's what you're looking for.

To quickly toggle that option on/off, see `:help 'pastetoggle'`.

Comment: Thanks . Finally I understood why we have :set paste !